# Anterpolation vs. Interpolation

Tags: numerical-methods

What is anterpolation, and how does it differ from [interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation)?  I cannot find a definition for the former, but I see it sometimes used (e.g. in the context of Fast Multipole Methods, like [here](http://mc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/images/6/62/Darve_2000.pdf)).

Comment: I found "performed by anterpolation, i.e., the adjoint of interpolation" and "anterpolation (transpose of interpolation)". Must be related somehow to multi-point evaluation.

Comment: Using the comment of LutzL, I found that anterpolation (the adjoint of interpolation) is considered as a Scaling operator. I read that 2D-interpolation is described as the passage from a coarse mesh to a fine mesh and that 2D-anterpolation as the opposite, *i.e.* the transition from a fine mesh to a coarse mesh. Does it make sense in your context ?